# SLIME compilation failing with only warnings

Tags: compiler-errors, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I have a program I'm trying to compile using SLIME and I am getting a `Compilation failed.` message even though my only `compiler notes` are all warnings.

The code compiles (with the same set of warnings) if I highlight it in its entirety and go to the menu option **SLIME > Compilation > Compile Region** but **Compile File** (C-c M-k) fails.

I suspect there is some sort of trigger or command I need to toggle to instruct SLIME to ignore warnings.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the log?

Comment: does the function COMPILE-FILE work?

Comment: I ultimately ended up figuring out that even though you're informed `Compilation failed` by SLIME, as long as I selected `y` for `Load fasl file anyway?` I was able to successfully run my program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kind of warnings you get is relevant.  `compile-file` is [specified](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm) to signify failure whenever compilation triggers a condition “*of type **error** or **warning** (other than **style-warning**)*”.  What a Common Lisp compiler calls a warning (as opposed to a style warning) is usually something that needs fixing.